Can't Use Keyboard Shortcut Since 4.1.1
This is my first post on this Forum. Looking forward to being part of this community.
I am relatively new to Blender but since starting I've had my Navigation keyboard shortcuts mapped to emulate that of Cinema 4D (which my muscle memory finds most comfortable).
So:
Rotate = Option & Left Mouse Button
Pan = Option & Middle Mouse Button
Zoom In/Out = Option & Right Mouse Button
These keyboard shortcuts have worked with pretty much the last five versions of Blender... until this latest one! Now, no matter what I do, I can't get the Pan keystrokes to work.
It's like some other command is overriding my settings and I have no idea what. Well, I have a clue:
When I try to use my usual shortcut (Option & Middle Mouse Button) I get an incremented line in grey across the screen with a blue number, that seems to indicate the current frame number in the timeline. If I move the mouse I advance along the timeline and that number updates.
This has never happened in any of the other versions of Blender I've used and I'd love to know how to get rid of it and reinstate my old keyboard shortcut.
If someone could help that would be amazing. Thanks so much,
ALEX


Hi. This is not a traditional forum. Might be useful to see this tour. Regarding the question- might this answer be helpful?

There may be an addon that causes this, try loading factory settings.

@KISKAart, would that be a valid solution for you if you were having this issue? Load factory settings? Certainly wouldn't be for me and I believe for a lot of users...

@MartynasŽiemys Loading factory settings works as a test if the user configuration is causing this, e.g. addons or keymap changes. It actually helped me when sculpting shortcuts didn't work.

Might make sense to do that for diagnosing in some cases. It must show up in active keymap in this case anyway.
